# GWT : Cursor position at the end when tab is pressed

Tags: java, gwt, setfocus

I have a link with two option edit & delete.
When some one click on the link a text box appears in that text box the content of the link will be appear but i need the cursor position at the end of the text without using mouse with the help of tab index only.

```
final TextBox editTb = new TextBox();
editTb.addStyleName(EDIT_FAV_DELETE_STYLE);
editTb.setText(favoriteBean.getName());

Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {

@Override
public void execute() {
 editFavoriteTb.setFocus(true);
}
    });
```

Already using setFocus(true) but this showing the cursor position at the start of the text i need it at the last.

Comment: Looks more like HTML and JavaScript. Please clarify this and show some code instead of explaining the problem as end user, you're a programmer and this is a site for professional and enthusiast programmers.

Comment: @TheNewIdiot : GWT...!!!

Comment: So where's the code with the problem?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza : Code is very big. I will try to post the part related with it.

Comment: Do not post all your code, post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: @VaibhavJain Have you tried [setCursorPos()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ValueBoxBase.html#setCursorPos(int)) ?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza : Ok...I will

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza : Can you check once.?

Comment: did you try editTb.setCursorPos( position ); ?

Comment: @Dilantha : I need the cursor position at the last for that what is the position..??

Comment: editTb.setCursorPos( favoriteBean.getName().length()); ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33683/discussion-between-vaibhav-jain-and-dilantha)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this

```
    final TextBox editTb = new TextBox();
    editTb.addStyleName(EDIT_FAV_DELETE_STYLE);
    editTb.setText(favoriteBean.getName());

    Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {

    @Override
    public void execute() {
     editFavoriteTb.setFocus(true);
     editTb.setCursorPos( favoriteBean.getName().length());
    }
  });
```